# How to Handle a certain, not reproducible error in datastep

Tags: sas

I got a really annoing problem with an SAS error regarding data step execution.
The error is not reproducible, but occuring a few times a week at diffrent code segments.
The error does not produce any warning or error entry in the log.
Only the following note is printed to the log:

```
NOTE: The DATA step has been abnormally terminated
```

The result of this error is a incomplete dataset.
The return code of the session the error occurs in is 0.

If I execute the same program again, the error does not occure any more.

So I need to take special meassures to detect the occurence of this special error.
I plan to do this by scanning the log for the given note.

Now I got two questions regarding this error:
1. Why does this error occure and can it be avoided?
2. Is there a more elegant solution to solve this problem than scanning the logs?

Every hint is appreciated.

thx

Edit: The dataset is not large (about 100.000 obs with 15 variables)

Edit2: The datastep is not running inside a macro.
       SAS Version is 9.2.
       OS is SunOS 5.10.
       I create datasets in work.
       Code is generated with SAS DI Studio 4.21.

Comment: You'll get better help if you give more information, such as what exactly happens, more of the log text around the NOTE: (is there an error, for example?), etc.

Comment: No error, no warning in the log and the returncode is zero as stated above. The other notes regarding the data step are usual notes like 'NOTE: There were 1159429 observations read from the data set abc.xyz.' and 'NOTE: The data set def.lmnop has 571808 observations and 17 variables.'. The note is all the information I get about the error and that is exactly my problem.

Comment: Does your data step happen to be running from inside a macro?  What version of SAS are you running?  What operating system?  Are you creating the dataset in a work library or in a libname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run in batch mode, SAS will normally automatically enter syntax check mode (ie, stop running code and just parse the code logic beyond that to tell you about obvious errors) if it encounters a serious error.  You can do this on purpose in DM by setting `OPTION DMSSYNCHK;`.  However, in your case this may not help - but it may be worth a shot if you're running in DM mode.

You also might look at the `&SYSERR.` and `&SYSTERRORTEXT.` macro variables.  Those store values based on the last data step or proc step run;  `&SYSERR=0` means it concluded successfully while other values mean it did not (excepting `&SYSERR=4` which means it ran but with a warning.)  `&SYSERRORTEXT.` contains the text that goes after `ERROR:` in the log from the most recent error.

I think you need to check `&SYSERR` first, as you might have an error that is from before the most recent data step (I don't think this is cleared by a successful run).  These may or may not contain information based on your issue, but it's worth checking (and perhaps a `%PUT _AUTOMATIC_;` right at the places it commonly errors at to see if there is a variable that contains useful information if not these).

See [the documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000208995.htm) for more details.

Additionally, you might try adding some code that occurs at the end of the data step.  Hard to say how to identify that without seeing your data step, but something like

```
%let step8complete=0;
data want;
 set sashelp.class end=eof;
 if eof then do;
   call symputx('step8complete','1');
 end;
run;
```

would allow you to query the macro variable &step8complete to see what it holds.

Finally, you may want to try to figure out if you can identify how many records ought to be in datasets you create, and test them to see if they have the right number of lines.  If they don't, then you have a potential issue.  PROC CONTENTS can tell you how many lines a dataset contains.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I will test them. Especially the last paragraph gave me a nice alternative idea for a solution. when I find a solution, I will post it here.

Comment: Added one more idea that might be more helpful in your specific situation.

Comment: Nice idea, I will try this approach also.